# He's shown up in my dreams vs he's been showing up in my dreams

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Supposing the speaker wanted to say ‘He’ keeps appearing in his/her dreams, not every day but lately tho and there is a possibility that the speaker will see him again in his/her dreams. I wonder which sentence is correct in this case.

1. He's shown up in my dreams
2. He's been showing up in my dreams

Answer (score 2):

"Has been showing" implies that it continues to happen, since it is in present tense.

"Has shown" does not make it clear if it continues, but is just stating that the event happened at least once in the past. (In my opinion, one would assume he no longer shows up in that case.)

Similar post [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/171785/use-of-shown-or-showing) (not quite a dupe).